# How to merge the values of different data volumes into a column using R language?

Tags: r, merge

How to merge the following data into a data frame of 89 rows and 1 column?

```
data1 <- rnorm(31,4,3)
data2 <- rnorm(28,4,2)
data3 <- rnorm(30,5,3)
```

Comment: From linked post: `data.frame(sapply(ls(pattern = "^data"), get))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be possible with

```
data.frame(c(data1, data2, data3))
```